# inclusion_tag does not work, i suppose he cant load the template

Tags: python, django, templates

I trying to make a templatetags for built all the bar in the site. I followed all the doc, but  it still not working.

i created the app "bar" and added to the app in settings.py
in /bar/

```
-- __init__.py
-- templatetags/
-- -- nav_bar.py
-- -- __init__.py
```

in /templates/
-- top_bar.html

Now nav_bar.py is:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('top_bar.html')
def show_topbar():
    user_login = 'prova'
    return {'user_login': user_login}
```

it does not have sense, but just for try. In future user_login will show if the user is logged, something like request.user.is_authenticated() and than others info.

```
top_bar.html is:

      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SkillAsk.com</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact {{ user }}'s</a></li>
  {% if user_login %}
<div class="navbar-form navbar-right"><a href="/accounts/logout/" class="btn btn-danger">Log Out</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" id="drop3" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    {{ user.username }}'s <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop3">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/backoffice/">Profilo</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/backoffice/setting">Impostazioni</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/backoffice/skills/add">Aggiungi Skill</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>



  <!-- Authenticate account menu -->
  {% else %}
            <form action="/accounts/login/?next=/backoffice" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="navbar-form navbar-right">{% csrf_token %}
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder="UserName" name="username" id="username" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
            </form>
  {% endif %}

          </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
```

(i tried even with a very simple template instead all that stuff but does not change the result)

now in base.html i loaded the templatetag with

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load nav_bar %}
bla bla bla
bla bla
```

and printed the template

```
 {{ show_topbar }}
```

...where i wanted to put the bar. Its seem very very very simple, but the output is nothing with no error.
If i delete the template top_bar.html nothing change, no error... if i change the template name, no error...

IMHO the problem is in register inclusion... Originally i wanted to use some response_to_render in return... but the example in docs dont use render.
Why i cant print my template in every page? I'm so curious!
Thank you

NOTE: just for info, i use another template called home.html that extend base...
p.s. in setting I defined the template dir... all the others template are still working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the variable syntax instead of the template tag syntax to call your tag. You should do this:

```
{% show_topbar %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your call to template tag is not good. You should use:

```
{% show_topbar %}
```

More informations : [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/)